# Zero measure of sub-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that a k-dimensional subspace S of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $k<n$) is of zero Lebesgue measure.
Now, I've seen this answered a few times but wanted to try a different proof.
My idea is basically (suppose n=3, k=2) to show that up to a rotation, S is the XY plane and is contained in the rectangle $(-\infty,+\infty)\times(-\infty,+\infty)\times\{0\}$ of measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then I can use the rotation invariance of the measure to conclude.
So I write $S=span\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$, the basis being orthonormal and try to find a rotation $\rho$ such that $\rho(v_i)=e_i$, $\{e_i\}$ being the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$.
I feel that this rotation could be a could candidate to show: $\rho(S)=\mathbb{R}^k$.
But does such a rotation even exist ? And then how can I show that $\rho(S)=\mathbb{R}^k$ ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to choose an orthonormal basis of your space $S$ and complete it to an orthonormal basis of $R^n$ (this is alway possible by Gram-Schmidt). Then the matrix that contains these vectors in *columns* represents the rotation that sends $R^k\times \{0\}$ to $S$. But for this to make sense, you need to know that Lebesgue measure is rotation-invariant.

Comment: Ohh yes it was implied that I knew that. I'll edit!  
I didn't get the matrix part. How can I write it explicitely ? And are you saying that the range of this matrix would be $\mathbb{R}^k$ ?

Comment: Complete $v_i$ into an orthonormal basis $(v_1,\ldots, v_k, w_1,\ldots, v_{n-k})$ of $\Bbb R^n$. The matrix $R$ that contains these vectors in columns is a rotation matrix that takes $\Bbb R^k\times \{0\}^{n-k}$ to $S$. (Equivalently, $R^T=R^{-1}$ takes $S$ into $\Bbb R^k$).